# Code block format breaks when sending more data row via (tabulate) - Python to slack

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, webhooks, slack-api, tabulate

When I run the following python script, instead of sending one message it sends in multiples and breaks the code block format as well as the tabulate/beautify/table format of the data. Maybe I'm not searching for the correct term to describe this behavior. All the necessary modules have been imported. Based on my testing it seems that the formatting breaks when I have more than 23 rows - see attached pic. As you can see I tried various method to send it. Please help

````html
df= pd.read_excel('samplefile_slack.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

pd.options.display.max_columns = None

from tabulate import tabulate
#Beautify Slack Output
#out = tabulate([list(row)for row in df.values], headers=list(df.columns), \
    #tablefmt="grid", stralign="center")

tbdf=tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql')

#tabulateout=tbdf.to_markdown()
 
   

slack_data = {"text":"``` " + str(tbdf) + " ```"}
       #slack_data = {"text":"```\n" + str(out) + "\n```"}
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, json=slack_data,headers=header)

if response.status_code != 200:
    raise ValueError(
        'Request to slack returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s'
        % (response.status_code, response.text)
        )
````

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw2sh.png)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was not with the row but with the character limit on slack code block formatting. The response was more than a certain characters and as a result the tabulate format was breaking and posting the message in however many chunks until it reached end of line